# For creating Autogenerated ID Column in Custom List Of SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

I have a custom list in which ID column is not there. I need to generate an auto generated ID Column i.e. whenever any entry adds into the list, the ID number should automatically gets incremented. 
The list i have created is manual, not from SharePoint designer. So, don't know how make this column without using SharePoint Designer. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: How's the ID column is not there?

Comment: use list default id column

Comment: SharePoint list comes with default ID column which get auto-incremented on every new Item. As suggested in below answer, edit the view and ID column in view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sharepoint Lists automatically have an column with **ID** which auto increments. You simply need to select this column from the **Modify View** screen to view it.

Go to Ribbon > Click on Modify View > Check the ID column

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This column exists in every SharePoint list. Edit the view of the current list, and you will see the ID there, it's auto incremented. You can add it to the default view to be able to view it.